# Can't get event blur with asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, events, onblur

Hi guys I've struggling how to get the event blur from a asp.net mvc 3 strongly typed view.
This is what i've tried.

```
<table>
 <td class="contentTable">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ciudad)
  </td>
  <td>
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ciudad, new{id= "mapSearch"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ciudad)
 </td>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#mapSearch').blur(function () {
           myFunction();
       });
});
</script>
```

myFunction is already a function that I'm using fired by a button, but now I wanted it fired by an event. I've also tryed with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ciudad, new{onblur= "mapSearch();"})
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, what's the html outputs of your code?

Comment: I'm using this to get the lat and long for google maps, so when you write the city (ciudad) the map loads the city on blur. myFunction is geocode()

Comment: What does `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ciudad, new{id= "mapSearch"})` become to? A `<input type='text'` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Change your View Markup like this

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ciudad)
```

and script like this

```
$(function () {
    $('#Ciudad').blur(function () {
           myFunction();
    });
});
```

Assuming you have a javascript function called `myFunction` exist

```
function myFunction() {
        console.debug("myFunction Called");
       //Some other awesome stuff here
}
```

JsFiddle sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/C3wMY/4/

Comment: I was trying that actually, but not working. same result with the changes you suggest.

Comment: @LeoJ: Are you getting any script errors ? See my updated answer with working sample.

Comment: No,I'm not getting any errors, i use firebug for debugging, I see that your example works perfectly but I still can't guess what I'm doing wrong. I'm thinking about to drop this and use a button :/

Answer (score 0):

EditorFor doesn't have an override that takes html attributes.  At the "EditorFor" level it doesn't know what elements may be getting inserted or how to get the attributes to them.  You need to use TextBoxFor, or DropDownListFor or another helper that adds a specific element.  Or you need to add the attributes in your editor template if that's the editor you are using.  You can pass attributes to your template if you want, but as part of the model (or ViewBag, or other ways).